# zram: swappiness, vfs_cache_pressure, page-cluster, dirty_ratio and dirty_background_ratio settings for gaming machines with HDD and low RAM?

Tags: kernel, hard-drive, games, performance, ram

I'm trying to game on Linux, but my biggest bottlenecks are my HDD and my 8GB of RAM. I used zram to allow more data to be stored in my RAM by compression (using lz4 algo with 100 priority and "discard" option along with the block size set equal to the amount of RAM I have). However, my system lags and keeps stuttering so badly and sometimes freezes when playing games even though the swap is just 5.7/7.7G full (the RAM is like 7.5/7.7G full though). Just right now I was trying to play COD:WW2 (wine) but it just kept lagging and freezing randomly. It happens with other heavy games as well.

I read different articles and I found some sysctl settings that would improve performance, however the recommendations on those articles are general and they're not specific, for example, neither to HDDs nor to gaming. These are the adjustable settings I'm talking about:

```
vm.swappiness
vm.vfs_cache_pressure
vm.page-cluster
vm.dirty_ratio
vm.dirty_background_ratio
```

On [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/mzun99/comment/h1cnvv3/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), I found these tweaks:

```
vm.swappiness = 200
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 200
vm.page-cluster = 0
vm.dirty_ratio = 2
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 1
```

And on [Hayden James blog](https://haydenjames.io/linux-performance-almost-always-add-swap-part2-zram/), I found these:

```
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 500
vm.swappiness = 100
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 1
vm.dirty_ratio = 50
```

Lastly, according to a formula [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/sysctl) these settings could work nicely (for general use):

```
vm.swappiness = 133
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 50
vm.dirty_ratio = 6
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 3
```

However, as I said, these settings are for general use and not gaming to keep the system stable when browsing for example. And as you can see, they differ a lot. Plus, I'm not very sure of what are the pros/cons of changing these settings.

I'm wondering if anyone could help me out with this? What would be the optimal values for these settings to work with zram to make the system more stable while gaming with an HDD and 8GB of RAM? I'm trying to keep low disk I/O and more RAM space. Quick note, even after disabling the swap partition on my HDD the issues still persists and keeping only the zram swap, thus it's not occurring because of that.

Comment: You may want to look at cgroups and move some processes into special cgroups.  Like, big memory wasters that don't need performance can go in a group that swaps out more and has a limited RSS.  Your game should get max memory with minimum swap.  If you use top and find your RSS memory hog, you can try to limit it or kill it. Things like this will help, but ultimately, you will just have to bite the bullet and get more ram.